# Why dwData = new IntPtr(0) would work in WM_COPYDATA (c# visual studio 2015)

Tags: c#, ipc, sendmessage, wm-copydata

When I set up the COPYDATASTRUCT, I set 
{

```
dwData = new IntPtr(0)
```

}
, and the sender would successfully send message to receiver. However, when I tried 
{

```
dwData = new IntPtr(xxOtherNumbersxxx)
```

}
, it would not work. Can anyone explain to me what dwData is really doing here? Thanks!

(P.S. I am a newbie software engineer with a really passionate heart to learn, so be gentle on my ratings.... plz.....)

Here is my source code for sender in C# :

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

// this application is a Sender
// made to work with a Receiver that is already made in Pascal by xxxxxx 
// The Receiver is located at 
// "K:\xxxxxxxxxxx"
// 
// This application is meant to send string "Hello World" to the Receiver
// if successful, the Receiver would appear on screen:
//
//                 WM_CopyData from: 3819
//                 Received string "Hello World!" at 6/3/2015
//
// Application:
// 1. Put "Hello World!" message into a data structure called "COPYDATASTUCT"
// 2. Find receiver by its app title "ReceiverMainForm" and its Class "TReceiverMainForm" (debug window: a pop-up window should show up with non-zero integers)
// 3. Send message in COPYDATASTRUCT through WM_COPYDATA code to receiver

namespace FindNotepad
{
    class Program
    {
      //include SendMessage
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, ref COPYDATASTRUCT lParam);

        //include SendMessage
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

        //this is a constant indicating the window that we want to send a text message
        const int WM_COPYDATA = 0x004A;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // ---------------- 1. set up message to be sent -----------------------
            //Put "Hello World!" message into a data structure called "COPYDATASTUCT"
            string msg = "Hello World!";
            var cds = new COPYDATASTRUCT
            {
                dwData = new IntPtr(0),
                cbData = msg.Length + 1,
                lpData = msg
            };
            // ---------------- 2. Find receiver application window -----------------------
            IntPtr receiverHandle = FindWindow("TReceiverMainForm", "ReceiverMainForm");

            // debug window pop-up
            MessageBox.Show(receiverHandle.ToString());


            // ---------------- 3. send message to receiver -----------------------
            try
            {
                SendMessage(receiverHandle, WM_COPYDATA, 3819, ref cds);
                // receiverHandle: handle for the receiver window
                // WM_COPYDATA: an application that sends WM_COPYDATA message to pass data to another application
                // 3819: handle of sender application, any preset integer can work. This is to distinguish which sender sends message on the receiver
                // ref cds: data structure that contains the message to be sent.
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        //Used for WM_COPYDATA for string messages
        public struct COPYDATASTRUCT
        {
            //dwData
            //The data to be passed to the receiving application.
            public IntPtr dwData;
            // cbData
            // The size, in bytes, of the data pointed to by the lpData member.
            public int cbData;
            // lpDATA
            // The data to be passed to the receiving application. This member can be NULL.
            public string lpData;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `new IntPtr(nonZeroValue)` is not how you would allocate memory for this. Google for working c# `WM_COPYDATA` samples and look at how they allocate memory.